# Reset ACF file size limits?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

So I had an 'image' input set to limit file sizes to 1mb. I've changed this to 2mb, but it still says "File size must not exceeed 1mb". Removing the restrictions completely doesn't help either. Has anyone encountered this before?

I could just delete the field and add a new one, but as we've made a ton of posts already I'd like to just resolve it with this field.

Before anyone asks, I'm certain it's not a server-level issue, as any new image fields don't suffer the same restrictions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried uploading a file that is larger than 1mb through your default media tab? Does it allows you to upload the file?

Comment: Yep, zero restrictions elsewhere - exclusively on the field that used to be limited to 1mb.

Comment: have you set both min and max value?

Comment: I didn't, but I don't think that'd be related. I think I've worked it out now, though! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Eugh, so I think I've worked it out.

For anyone else stuck on the same thing, I did the following:

- Export all the fields out as json
- Find the 'max_size' fields, and change them there manually
- Delete existing fields and re-import
- Find each post, and click 'update' before trying to upload anything

Must be some weird bug with ACF...